# ffmpeg - Is is possible to create a video from image tiles

Tags: ffmpeg

With ffmpeg, you can:

- create a video from a list of images
- create an image with tiles representing frames of a video

but, how is it possible to create a video from tiles, in a picture, representing frames of a video?

if I have this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "scale=320:240,tile=12x25" out.png
```

I will get an image (out.png) made of 12x25 tiles of 320x240 pixels each.

I am trying to reverse the process and, from that image, generate a video.

Is it possible?

Edit with more details:
What am I really trying to achieve is to convert a video into a gif preview. But in order to make an acceptable gif, I need to build a common palette. So, either I scan the movie twice, but it would be very long since I have to do it for a large batch, or I make a tiled image with all the frames in a single image, then make a gif with a palette computed from all the frames, which would be significantly faster... if possible.

Comment: "create a video from tiles, in a picture" what?  Can you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do, and perhaps show an image as an example?  You want to take an image, effectively crop it iteratively, and make a video out of those crops?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it; essentially take an image that is made of tiles and take each tile; an example of such image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idqyz.jpg  I can easily build such as image with ffmpeg, but I'm trying to find out if I can build a video from a picture like this; actually it's to build an animated gif, but I need all the frames in one picture to calculate one palette. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Aren't you processing each video twice anyway? Once to generate the mosaic and once to make the GIF (+ once to generate palette). How are you generating the palette - ffmpeg?

Comment: I would use ffmpeg: ideally I scan the original mp4 once, which is the long part of the process and make the tiles and output the common palette (using the palettegen filter). After that I could encode the video from the tiles using the palette, but I expect this pass to be very short. I could output a series of images and get the same result, but it will take slightly longer; we're talking about 200k files, so shaving even 1 second out of the process is important

Comment: Do you need the tiled image for some other purpose?

Comment: yes, it is used for facial recognition as well and it is faster to scan one frame with many thumbnails rather than multiple images to find faces.

Comment: Ok, it's technically possible to do the palette gen and apply in one command, but there may be a speed cost. It's also possible to combine some filters to do the tiles -> frames, but it's late here, so I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138276/discussion-between-thomas-and-mulvya).